# Parsing Json objects inside objects using Gson and get the length

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json file like below and want to parse the overlays like `overlay1,overlay2,overlay3`:

```
{
    "overlays": {
        "overlay1": {
             "imagesFPS": 12,
             "clickThrough": false,
             "repeatCount": 0,
             "sensitivity": 0.6,
         },
         "overlay2": {
             "cgButtonPressedColor": "#ffaa56",
             "relative": "screen",
             "isOverlayRendered": true,
             "cgBorderWidth": "0px",
         },
         "overlay3": {
             "cgButtonPressedColor": "#007f00",
             "text": "Goto Page3 on Touch 5 Release",
         }
    }
}
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonObject job = gson.fromJson(fileReader, JsonObject.class);
JsonObject ovl = job.getAsJsonObject("overlays");
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    JsonObject overlay = ovl.getAsJsonObject("overlay" + i);
    if (overlay != null) {
        osb.setOverlay(jsp.getOverlay(overlay));
    }
}
```

How can I get the length of overlays (here: `overlay1`, `overlay2`, `overlay3`)? How do I query the length of `3` via the gson API?

And I want to know the `overlay1,overlay2,overlay3` in a string or array so that I can iterate over them.

Note: Here I have to iterate 100 times or any times so that I can iterate if overlays increase later in json file. It iterates unnecessarily in looping.
How can I iterate only `overlay1` or `overlay2` or `overlay3` and so without unnecessary iterating?
I mean I just want to get the `overlay1`, `overlay2`, `overlay3` and so on in `jsonobjects` via Gson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this using this code below.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
JsonObject job = gson.fromJson(fileReader, JsonObject.class); 
JsonObject ovl = job.getAsJsonObject("overlays");
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(ovl, type); 
Iterator<String> entries = data.keySet().iterator(); 
while (entries.hasNext()) 
{ JsonObject overlay = ovl.getAsJsonObject(entries.next().toString()); 
   if (overlay != null)
     { 
       osb.setOverlay(jsp.getOverlay(overlay));
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an array instead of wrapped objects?

```
{
    "overlays": [
        {"overlay1": {
             "imagesFPS": 12,
             "clickThrough": false,
             "repeatCount": 0,
             "sensitivity": 0.6,
         }},
         {"overlay2": {
             "cgButtonPressedColor": "#ffaa56",
             "relative": "screen",
             "isOverlayRendered": true,
             "cgBorderWidth": "0px",
         }},
         {"overlay3": {
             "cgButtonPressedColor": "#007f00",
             "text": "Goto Page3 on Touch 5 Release",
         }}
    ]
}
```

And using this code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject job = gson.fromJson(fileReader, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray  ovl = job.getAsJsonArray("overlays");

if (ovl != null) {
    osb.setOverlay(jsb.getOverlay(ovl.get(ovl.lenght() - 1)));
}
```

Or if you want to use wrapped json objects, you should create a list and insert elements like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<JsonObject> overlays = new LinkedList<>();
JsonObject job = gson.fromJson(fileReader, JsonObject.class);
JsonObject ovl = job.getAsJsonObject("overlays");

for (int i = 1; ; ++i) {
    JsonObject overlay = ovl.getAsJsonObject("overlay" + i);
    if (overlay == null) {
        break;
    } else {
        overlays.put(overlay);
    }
}

// Use "overlays" list
```

Comment: thanks for your reply dan. but if my json contains overlay4 instead of overlay 3 then this code will not work.. All i need is to get overlay names , like overlay1,overlay2 and so on.. actually i am already using list to push my overlays inside my code but i need the names to push..

Comment: I have solved this issue by following
         'Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
          JsonObject job = gson.fromJson(fileReader, JsonObject.class);
         JsonObject ovl = job.getAsJsonObject("overlays")'
         Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(ovl, type);
  Iterator<String> entries = data.keySet().iterator();
  while (entries.hasNext()) {
   JsonObject overlay =                   ovl.getAsJsonObject(entries.next().toString());
   if (overlay != null) {
    osb.setOverlay(jsp.getOverlay(overlay));
   }
  }'